# Mesh eyelashes "smear" when eyelids are closed with an armature

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, bezier-curves

I converted eyelashes from curve to mesh, and attached them to my main model with a Surface Deform modifier.

The main model was already rigged, so I used a Data Transfer modifier -> Vertex Data -> Vertex Groups to copy the weights to the eyelashes.

In the Modifier tab, the Surface Deform modifier is first, followed by the Data Transfer modifier.

The problem is when I close the eyes using the armature, the eyelashes "smear".

The eyelashes lose their shape, and become warped.

**Before: Eye open in rest pose** 
[image: Before: Eye open in rest pose]

**After: Eye closed using armature**
[image: After: Eye closed using armature]

I tried changing the order of the modifiers, using Mesh Deform and Simple Deform, using Smooth Corrective and Smooth Laplacian, and Warp. Using Join instead of Surface Deform has the same issue.

I'm really at a loss. Is there some kind of collision happening between the eyelash mesh and main mesh? Could it be a weight issue? Is there a better way to attach curve (attached to a controller) or mesh eyelashes? Hopefully, someone has seen this before. 

This is Blender version 3.1.0.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the eyelash object and not the stretched texture of the eyelids? What do the lids look like when you hide the eyelash object?

Comment: To me it looks like stretched eyelid texture as well. Or if it's really the eyelashes, maybe the weight painting isn't correct so that the tips of the lashes are not moved by the armature.